# Add values into two columns in a table using data in one textbox

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4.1, detailsview, templatefield

I'm developing an `asp.net` web-forms application with `entity framework`. There are two columns in my database table to add `Latitude` and `Longitude`. But I don't want to add two `TextBoxes` in user interface to add them.

I need to add one `TextBox` to add those data, separated by comma. (ex: 85.06000,25.01200). when user clicks submit button, I need to split this string up and add the result to `Latitude` and `Longitude` columns in database table.

I have created the form to insert data using `DetailsView` with `TemplateField`.

I'm new to asp.net and C#. How could I do this ?

Comment: what's your problem? splitting? or working with database?

Comment: You need to handle the `event - xxxxInserting` of `DetailsView` and call the `FindControl` method to get the reference of `TextBox`.

Comment: @AVD i have added `OnItemInserting` event. but it's not working. see my [latest post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037215/asp-net-detailsview-oniteminserting-is-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

To separate string on two parts you can use `string.Split(`) method.

if you have variable latitudeandlongitude:

```
var splittedArray = latitudeandlongitude.Split(',');

if(splittedArray.Length!=2)
    throw new ArgumentException();
var latitude = splittedArray[0];
var longitude = splittedArray[1];
```

But i'm not recommend you to do such things (use one textbox for two different variables). It will be source of user errors and they will hate you.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] parts = txtInput.Text.Trim().Split(',');
string Latitude = parts[0];
string Longitude = parts[1];
```

now you have seperated them and you can send them to your DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the value like this :-

```
string[] arr=TextBox1.Text.Split(',');
```

and then prepare insert statement like :-

```
Insert into yourtable("Latitude","Longitude") values(arr[0],arr[1]);
```